# Does the game ShadowCaster support keyboard controls?

Tags: shadowcaster

It's common that DOS games have a keyboard and some use both keyboard & mouse to play the game. But ShadowCaster seems to only be controlled by mouse - for being a first-person shooter, this is quite tiresome. Anyone know how I can play with a keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not WASD. You have to **use the arrow keys or the number pad**.

I suggest using the number pad, as 1 and 3 let you strafe, and both 8 and 5 will move you forward.

If you're having problems getting it to work try editing `keyboardlayout=auto` in the config as per the [DOSBox manual](http://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html#KeyboardLayout) if you're not using a keyboard with the standard 101 layout, or if you're not running a Windows OS.